# Solr optimize command status

Tags: solr

I have run the solr optimize command using update?optimize=true.  Can any one pls tel me how to check the status of Solr optimize command?  I am using Solr 3.5  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the optimize is running, you can run the `top` command, type `M` to sort by memory usage, and watch the RES and SHR columns increase for the SOLR java process. Also keep and eye on Mem: free at the top of the screen. As long as RES and SHR are increasing, optimize is working. In fact the only thing that will stop it would be if Mem: free goes down to zero.

If that happens to you, rerun optimize with a LARGER number for maxSegments. For instance if 5 segments runs out of RAM, try 9. Then run again with 8, then again with 7, then try 5 again, and 3 and 1.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. I ll check it on next optimize.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to check the status of the index after an optimize, is to browse to `http://<your instance & core>/admin/stats.jsp`. This is also the same as clicking [Statistics] link off of the Solr Admin page.

If you look in the **stats:** section once on that page, typically after an optimize, the **numDocs** and **maxDoc** values will be the same as all pending deletes will have occurred. Also the **reader** value should show a value that contains `segments=1` at the end. This will be the case as the optimize command will force the index to be merged into one section as explained below in this excerpt from the [UpdateXmlMessages](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22) section for optimize in the Solr Wiki.

> An optimize is like a hard commit except that it forces all of the
>   index segments to be merged into a single segment first.

Comment: Thanks.. i have another doubt rather a clarification. optimize are usefult after updates/delta-imports correct? wen we ve just indexed the data for the first time thts done full-import for the first time it wont ve any effect right? or will they be useful even then..?

Comment: From the wiki link in my answer "Depending on the use cases, this operation should be performed infrequently (like nightly), if at all, since it is very expensive and involves reading and re-writing the entire index. Segments are normally merged over time anyway (as determined by the merge policy), and optimize just forces these merges to occur immediately." Since it is expensive, I would recommend limiting the use of optimize to only when necessary. Perhaps after a full-import, especially if you are clearing the index prior to the full-import.